# How can I share my hosted app's code in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-code

I'm trying but can not seem to find the answer via googling.I know that using Google App Engine SDK plugin from my IDE I can deploy my app to `someapp.appspot.com`.So, my question is : is it possible I can share link to my web project code by just deploying it to App engine  do I have to upload it separately on `code.google.com` or something?   -thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uploading your code makes it available to nobody. To share your code use code.google.com or bitbucket or github etc etc.

You could also share your code on github then use "push to deploy" to keep everything in sync.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/push-to-deploy

> Push-to-Deploy is feature of App Engine that allows you to deploy an
>   application by pushing its source files from a Git repository to a
>   remote repository hosted on the Google Cloud Platform. The Cloud
>   repository is a fully-functional Git repository that supports standard
>   Git operations like push, pull, clone and log. You can use
>   Push-to-Deploy to deploy directly from a Git repository on your local
>   workstation or via a connected repository hosted on GitHub. When you
>   push your code, Push-to-Deploy automatically uploads and launches the
>   application. Push-to-Deploy works for applications written in Python,
>   PHP and Java.

Answer (score 1):

Deploy via github/bitbucket has been discontinued.  Only the good ol' appcfg.py is supported:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/getting-started/deploying-the-application

It appears that all the old github/bitbucket deploy doc links are dead.